# add small ribbon button to PublishItemsGroup

Tags: tridion

sorry if this has been covered. I have found how to add a new ribbon toolbar group of small buttons, but I can't seem to find (or figure out) how to add a small button to an existing group of small buttons. I'm trying to add a new button to the PublishItemsGroup (under Publish/Unpublish to the right of Publishing Queue button). If I do this, it creates a whole new group:

```
   <ext:ribbontoolbars>
      <ext:add>
        <ext:extension pageid="HomePage" 
                       groupid="PublishItemsGroup" 
                       name="Expire" 
                       assignid="ext_expireWorkflow_Btn">
          <ext:command>StartWorkflowExpiration</ext:command>
          <ext:title>Expire</ext:title>
                        <ext:issmallbutton>true</ext:issmallbutton>
          <ext:dependencies>
            <cfg:dependency>mycompany.Resources.Workflow.StartWorkflowExpiration</cfg:dependency>
          </ext:dependencies>
          <ext:apply>
            <ext:view name="DashboardView">
              <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar"/>
            </ext:view>
          </ext:apply>
        </ext:extension>
      </ext:add>
    </ext:ribbontoolbars>
```

but, if I just use "PublishGroup" then it puts the small button to the right of Publish/Unpublish (not under)

```
<ext:ribbontoolbars>
  <ext:add>
    <ext:extension pageid="HomePage" 
                   groupid="PublishGroup" 
                   name="Expire" 
                   assignid="ext_expireWorkflow_Btn">
      <ext:command>StartWorkflowExpiration</ext:command>
      <ext:title>Expire</ext:title>
                        <ext:issmallbutton>true</ext:issmallbutton>
      <ext:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>mycompany.Resources.Workflow.StartWorkflowExpiration</cfg:dependency>
      </ext:dependencies>
      <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="DashboardView">
          <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar"/>
        </ext:view>
      </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
  </ext:add>
</ext:ribbontoolbars>
```

Is it possible to add a small button to that group? or do I have to override and create a whole new group and then hide the existing PublishItemsGroup?
thanks
~Warner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to add small button to existing sub-group (group has title on the bottom and they are separated with vertical lines).
And yes, you can add new group with your button in the sub-group and hide the original group.

Answer (score 5):

I've written an explanation on how to use the Ribbon Item Group on [tridiondeveloper.com](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/ribbon-item-group). It is basically a Tridion User Control (.ascx) that you need to specify, and you specify the Ribbon Items Group as an extension in your extension Configuration file.

Comment: that's what I used to make it work. but I was hoping there was some way to use that approach to add a button to an existing sub-group. obviously not. but I was able to add a new group with the OOB buttons. thanks!

Comment: Because of the way its setup (through a user control) its unfortunately impossible to add a button to an existing group through your own extension indeed.